# Nmap Error when using the "–script" arg

Tags: networking, scripting, ubuntu-12.04, nmap

i just installed the nmap network scanner,
and when i try to use it whith the "-script" parameter, it doesn't work:
example:

```
soufiane@soufiane-cvc:/usr/local$ nmap -p143,993 -Pn –script imap-capabilities 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-03 10:07 WEST
Failed to resolve "–script".
Failed to resolve "imap-capabilities".
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000025s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
143/tcp closed imap
993/tcp closed imaps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
```

i'm using ElementaryOS Freya (ubuntu 12.04 i guess).
any ideas ??

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `–-script` (with two dashes), not `-script`.

**EDIT:**  (following your comment)

No problem here. My output:

```
$ nmap -p143,993 -Pn --script imap-capabilities 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-03 16:36 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
143/tcp closed imap
993/tcp closed imaps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds
```

Comment: soufiane@soufiane-cvc:~$ nmap -p143,993 -Pn -–script imap-    capabilities 127.0.0.1
nmap: unrecognized option '-–script'
Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org )
Usage: nmap [Scan Type(s)] [Options] {target specification}
TARGET SPECIFICATION:

Comment: Edited my answer, no problem here with my nmap 6.47. Does your local nmap man page mention the `--script` option, or I you using it because you saw it on the website documentation?

Comment: i just rebooted my computer and it worked. and you was right, it's `--script` the correct parameter

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with how you copy/paste from your terminal to SO, but really, copying your exact text, I have a problem with your dashes, what I see is a nomal dash, and then kind of a long dash. If I copy/paste your **exact** command: `$ nmap -p143,993 -Pn -–script imap- capabilities 127.0.0.1
nmap: unrecognized option '-–script'
Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org )
Usage: nmap [Scan Type(s)] [Options] {target specification}
(and the basic help with list of options)`. Could you try copy/paste **my** command to your terminal?

Comment: i guess you're right, i tried your version and it worked. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8086 localhost
```